# PHP __set magic method not being called

Tags: php

I am currently making an API that is based around objects. I have an abstract class called `Part` that every child  extends. `Part` has a `__set` function that stores values in a protected array called `$attributes`. However, when I do `$part->user = new User(etc...);` it doesn't run the `__set` function. Here is my  code:

Part:

```
<?php

namespace Discord;

abstract class Part
{
    protected $attributes = [];

    public function __construct(array $attributes)
    {
        $this->attributes = $attributes;

        if (is_callable([$this, 'afterConstruct'])) {
            call_user_func([$this, 'afterConstruct']);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Handles dynamic get calls onto the object.
     * 
     * @param  string $name 
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function __get($name)
    {
        $str = '';

        foreach (explode('_', $name) as $part) {
            $str .= ucfirst($name);
        }

        $funcName = "get{$str}Attribute";

        if (is_callable([$this, $funcName])) {
            return call_user_func([$this, $funcName]);
        }

        if (!isset($this->attributes[$name]) && is_callable([$this, 'extraGet'])) {
            return $this->extraGet($name);
        }

        return $this->attributes[$name];
    }

    /**
     * Handles dynamic set calls onto the object.
     *
     * @param string $name 
     * @param mixed $value 
     */
    public function __set($name, $value)
    {
        echo "name: {$name}, value: {$value}";
        $this->attributes[$name] = $value;
    }
}
```

Client:

```
<?php

namespace Discord\Parts;

use Discord\Part;
use Discord\Parts\User;

class Client extends Part
{
    /**
     * Handles extra construction.
     * 
     * @return void
     */
    public function afterConstruct()
    {
        $request = json_decode($this->guzzle->get("users/{$this->id}")->getBody());

        $this->user = new User([
            'id'        => $request->id,
            'username'  => $request->username,
            'avatar'    => $request->avatar,
            'guzzle'    => $this->guzzle
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Handles dynamic calls to the class.
     *
     * @return mixed 
     */
    public function __call($name, $args)
    {
        return call_user_func_array([$this->user, $name], $args);
    }

    public function extraGet($name)
    {
        return $this->user->{$name};    
    }
}
```

When I create a new instance of `Client` it automatically creates a `User` instance and sets it. However, I have testing code in `__set` and it doesn't run.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The `__set` magic method is called *only* when a property is inaccessible from the context in which it is set](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.set). Because `Client` extends `Part`, the  properties of `Part` are all accessible in `Client`, so the magic method isn't needed.

Comment: Thanks, still a bit confused however. How could I go about fixing this?

Comment: @cheese5505 It depends on exactly what you need to do. You could use (1) a property-specific setter, (2) a generic setter that takes a property name and a value, or (3) a container or wrapper of some type that operates on `Part`, if you really need the magic method to work.

Comment: I need to be able to run `$client->user` to retrieve `$client->attributes['user']` as well as `$client->user = etc` to set `$client->attributes['user']`. Which would be my best option? Could you also point me in the direction to doing it? Thanks!

Comment: @cheese5505 Honestly, you probably want to think twice about going that route. I am dealing with some very similar code tonight, in fact, and it's making my molars hurt... I would probably go with a property-specific getter and setter, so that it's clear you're doing something special by calling those methods. Otherwise, this kind of thing leads to very subtle bugs.